# CombineLatest of dynamic array inside switchMap is unsubscribing and re-subscribing continuously

Tags: rxjs

I have at least two buttons that I want to dynamically listen for clicks on. `listeningArray$` will emit an array (`ar`) of button #'s that I need to be listening to. When somebody clicks on one of these buttons I'm listening to, I need to console log that the button that was clicked and also log the value from a time interval.

If `ar` goes from `[1,2]` to `[1]`, we need to stop listening to clicks on button #2. So the DOM click event needs to be removed for `2` and that should trigger the `.finally()` operator. But for `1`, we should remain subscribed and the code inside the `.finally()` should not run, since nothing is being unsubscribed.

```
const obj$ = {};

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  Rx.Observable.interval(2000),
  listeningArray$ // Will randomly emit either [1] or [1,2]
)
.switchMap(([x, ar]) => {
    const observables = [];

    ar.forEach(n => {
        let nEl = document.getElementById('el'+n);

        obj$[n] = obj$[n] || Rx.Observable.fromEvent(nEl, 'click')
          .map(()=>{
            console.log(' el' + n);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            console.log(' FINALLY_' + n);
          });

        observables.push(obj$[n]);
    })

    return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(...observables);
})
.subscribe()
```

But what's happening is every time the interval emits a value, the DOM events ALL get removed and then immediately get added on again, and the code inside the .finally operator runs for `1` *and* `2`.

This is really frustrating me. What am I missing?

It's a bit of a complex situation, so I created this: https://jsfiddle.net/mfp22/xtca98vx/7/

Comment: Try to better describe the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: @MarkvanStraten Thanks for the tip. I've restructured my question. Hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was actually really close, but I misunderstood the point of `switchMap`.

`switchMap` is designed to unsubscribe from the observable it returns whenever a new value is emitted from above. This is why it can be used to cancel old pending Http requests when a new request needs to be made instead.

The problem I was having is to be expected. `switchMap` will unsubscribe from the previously returned observable before subscribing to the current one. This was unacceptable, as I explained in the question. The reason this was unacceptable was that in my actual project, the `fromEvent` observables were listening to Firebase `child_added` events, so when these cold observables went from having no subscribers to having 1 subscriber, Firebase would subsequently fire the event for every child already existing, as well as for future ones added.

I played with `mergeMap` for a while, but it was really difficult and buggy to manually have to unsubscribe from previously returned observables.

So I added a subscriber for the inner observables while `switchMap` was doing its process of `unsubscribe from old => subscribe to new` so that there would always be a subscriber. I used `takeUntil(Observable.timer(0))` to make sure the subscribers didn't build up and cause a memory leak.

There may be a better solution, but this was the best one I found.

```js
const obj$ = {};

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  Rx.Observable.interval(2000),
  listeningArray$ // Will randomly emit either [1] or [1,2]
)
.switchMap(([x, ar]) => {
  const observables = [];

  ar.forEach(n => {
    let nEl = document.getElementById('el'+n);

    obj$[n] = obj$[n] || Rx.Observable.fromEvent(nEl, 'click')
      .map(()=>{
        console.log(' el' + n);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log(' FINALLY_' + n);
      })
      .share();
    
    obj$[n].takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(0))
      .subscribe();
    observables.push(obj$[n]);
  })

  return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(...observables);
})
.subscribe()
```

I also had to add the `.share()` method. I was going to need it anyway. I'm using this pattern to let some Angular components declare what data they need, ignoring what other components might want, to achieve a better separation of concerns. So multiple components can subscribe to the same Firebase observables, but the `.share()` operator ensures that each message from Firebase is only handled once (I'm dispatching actions to a Redux store for each one).

Working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mfp22/xtca98vx/8/

Comment: An update from the year 2023: RxJS `share` has an option `resetOnRefCountZero` that you can define like this: `resetOnRefCountZero: () => timer(0)`

That keeps the observable subscribed to until the next tick, so a `switchMap` unsubscribing temporarily will not cause the upstream observable to complete.

Answer (score 3):

State in FRP is immutable. Thus when you switchMap to the second emission the previous observable `combineLatest` containing `[1,2]` will get unsubscribed and the finally operator invoked. Before subscribing to the next containing only `[1]`

If you only want to unsubscribe from one button you can store state in the DOM (add atr to button) and use `filter` to ignore button.
Or you can add a `TakeWhile()` to every button dictating when it should be unsubscribed so it can invoke it's own `finally()`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I misunderstood what switchMap was supposed to do. You put me on the right track. I'll be answering soon with a simple solution I came up with.